# Structure of k[G]/J(k[G]) when char k divides |G|

Tags: representation-theory

I'm self-learning representation theory, so I'd like if possible someone kind to help me with the following.

Given a field $k$ whose characteristic does not divide the order of a finite group $G$, we know from Maschke's theorem that the group ring $k[G]$ is semisimple. Conversely, if $R=k[G]$ is semisimple, the characteristic of $k$ does not divide $G$ with some extra-work. Now, let's say I have some group $G$ for which $\operatorname{char} k$ divides $|G|$; for instance $G = A_{4}$ (the alternating group on $4$ letters) and $F=\mathbb{F}_{3}$. What is the structure of $R/J(R)$ in this case? Since $R$ is left-Artinian, it must be that $R/J(R)$ is semisimple; but how can one write down the simple submodules from the Wedderburn decomposition/the Jordan-Holder decomposition of $J(R)$ (what are the quotients?)/etc. I'd really like to learn these things well, so maybe doing it for the above example in detail would help more than telling me the theorems in detail. Thanks a lot!

Edit: Here $J(R)$ denotes the Jacobson radical of ring $R$.

Comment: This question I asked once could be helpful. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594683/compute-the-jacobson-radical-of-the-group-ring-mathbbf-2s-3

Comment: Very helpful, thanks; however my questions aren't answered there; can someone still look at this?