# Compute the Jacobson radical of $R=\mathbb{F}_3[S_3]$ and find all simple $R$-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Compute the Jacobson radical of $R=\mathbb{F}_3[S_3]$ and find all simple $R$-modules.

I need to find a surjective map and compute its kernel. But I am not sure which map. Any hints?

Comment: What kind of surjective map are you looking for? Anyway, it seems that $(1)(2)(3)+(123)+(321)$ (the sum over elements in $A_3=C_3$) is in the radical. Dunno if there's anything not generated by it though...

Comment: http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/modules12/exam12.pdf Maybe question 4 here helps?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594683/compute-the-jacobson-radical-of-the-group-ring-mathbbf-2s-3?rq=1

Comment: Yes it is but the question didn't include simple modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The starting idea is that when the characteristic of the field and the order of the group are not coprime, you are going to have a nonzero Jacobson radical. Because the ring is Artinian, the Jacobson radical must be a nilpotent ideal. If we succeed in finding a nilpotent ideal $I$ such that $R/I$ has zero radical, then we can be assured that $J(R)=I$. (You will need to understand and fully justify this strategy for yourself.)

Like the document you referenced, I like to use $\sigma$ for the generator of order $3$ and $\tau$ for the generator of order $2$.

By the Freshman's dream theorem, $(1-\sigma)^3=1-\sigma^3=0$, so $1-\sigma$ is nilpotent. We'd also like to prove that $(1-\sigma)r$ is nilpotent for any other $r\in R$, but since $1-\sigma$ isn't central, this isn't immediately obvious.

But $(1-\sigma)$ does satisfy a weaker property that does the trick, namely that $(1-\sigma)R=R(1-\sigma)$. The rule $(1-\sigma)\tau=\tau(1+\sigma)(1-\sigma)$ allows you to commute $(1-\sigma)$ from the left of the product $(1-\sigma)r$ to the right to get $r'(1-\sigma)$ for some $r'\in R$. Likewise $(1-\sigma)r'=r''(1-\sigma)$. Then $(1-\sigma)R=R(1-\sigma)$ is a two sided ideal and
$$
((1-\sigma)r)^3=(s-\sigma)r(s-\sigma)r(s-\sigma)r\\= (s-\sigma)rr'(s-\sigma)(s-\sigma)r\\=r'r''(s-\sigma)(s-\sigma)(s-\sigma)r=0
$$

This establishes that $(1-\sigma)R$ is a nilpotent ideal, and hence is contained in the Jacobson radical.

Now let's focus on the kernel of the map $F_3[S_3]\to F_3[S_3/\langle\sigma\rangle]$. Of course, everything in $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is mapped to the identity of the quotient, so $1-\sigma$ is in the kernel.

If $\sum r_g g \mapsto 0$, we know that $\sum_{g\in\langle\sigma\rangle}r_g=0$ and $\sum_{g\in G\setminus\langle\sigma\rangle}r_g=0$

Given that, a little reverse engineering (or just plain long division) shows that
$$(\sigma-1)((r_{\sigma^2}+r_\sigma)1+r_{\sigma^2}\sigma+(r_{\sigma\tau}+r_{\sigma^2\tau})\tau+r_{\sigma^2\tau}\sigma\tau=\sum r_gg$$

demonstrates that $\sum r_gg$ is in $(1-\sigma)R$. So the kernel is equal to this ideal.

By Maschke's theorem, the second group ring is semisimple; moreover, it is commutative. The only two possibilities are that it is a $F_9$ or that it is $F_3\times F_3$. It can't be $F_9$ though: $(1-\tau)(1+\tau)=0$ shows there are zero divisors in $F_3[S_3/\langle\sigma\rangle]$.

Thus $R/J(R)$ has two distinct maximal ideals corresponding to two nonisomorphic simple modules. As an exercise you can attempt to describe the maximal right ideals of the original ring that correspond to these.

Comment: What is G? Is it S3?

Comment: @Bob $G=S_3$. The double subscripts were going to get messy

Comment: Just to clarify the simple R-module is F3xF3?

Comment: @Bob no: the original ring shares the same simple modules as F3xF3, of which there are two. F3xF3 is not simple as a module over itself

Comment: So R is isomorphic to F3*F3, but how do I find the simple modules of this?

Comment: @Bob $R$ is *not* isomorphic to F3xF3. You should be abl to work out the simple modules of a product of fields on your own or with help of other questions here

Comment: What do you mean by second group ring? And how do I do I work out Thus R/J(R) has two distinct maximal ideals corresponding to two nonisomorphic simple modules

Comment: @Bob there are only two group rings here: the other one is $F[S_3/\langle\sigma\rangle]$

Comment: So F[S3/<sigma>] is isomorphic to F3xF3? I'm not sure how you use Maschke Theorem here.

Comment: @Bob I want you to work on the simple submodules of products of fields on your own for a while.

Comment: @Bob the group has order 2, 2 is a unit in $F_3$ so the second ring is a $2$ dimensional semisimple $F_3$ algebra. It is a direct application of maschke

Comment: I understand why I need to calculate the maximal ideal but how do I find them? Could you provide an example

Comment: I have a homomorphism from S3 to {+/- 1} does this help?

Comment: @Bob  see this about ideals http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2048122/29335

Comment: So in our case $R(0,1)(1-\sigma)$ and $R(1,0)(1-\sigma)$?

Comment: @Bob $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$  have no meaning in $R$. Take a day to think the pieces over carefully. It sounds like you are rushing.

Comment: I get simple modules as F3x0 and 0xF3 is that right?

Comment: @Bob YES, this is correct. Do you understand why $R$ and $R/J(R)$ share the same simple modules? If you do, then we can start working harder on finding them in $R[S_3/\langle\sigma\rangle]$ and lifting them to $R$.

Comment: Yes, I understand why they share the same simple modules.

Comment: How would I find them? and what do you mean by lift?

Comment: @Bob To find some idempotents in any group ring: take any subgroup $H<G$, sum the elements of $H$, then divide that by $|H|$. The result is an idempotent. This will lead you to the idempotents of $F_3[S_3/\langle\sigma\rangle]$ that split it into two simple submodules. Lifting: if you find a maximal right ideal $T$ of $R/I$, then there must be a maximal ideal $T'$ of $R$ such that $T=T'/I$, by correspondence. This gives you the two maximal right ideals in $R$ that you need from the maximal right ideals in $R/I$.

Comment: $A_3$ is a subgroup of $S_3$. $A_3={1,(1,2,3) and (1,3,2)}$. Sum=1+(1,2,3)+(1,3,2). Divide by 3. I don't understand anything after this point.

Comment: @Bob You ought to be working in $S_3/\langle \sigma\rangle\cong \{1,\tau\}$, not $S_3$ itself.  But anyway, the trick works for $\frac13(1+\sigma+\sigma^2)$: $(\frac13(1+\sigma+\sigma^2))^2=\frac19(3+3\sigma+3\sigma^2)=\frac13(1+\sigma+\sigma^2)$.

Comment: I think I can put the simple R-modules are F3x0 and 0xF3 in my question. Don't think I need the rest. Thanks